# How to create multi-items slider in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a multi-items carousel and it's fetching all images from the database but only displaying 3 images. I need this carousel to display all images from the database when one click on side arrows. How can I make it work as  "https://react-multi-carousel.now.sh/" this carousel? Can you help me with my custom carousel?

```css
.home__wrapper {
  .categoryslider__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.05s, height 0.05s linear;
    height: auto;


    .category {
      position: relative;
      height: 14vh;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      cursor: pointer;

      & >img {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }

      p {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0.2em;
        left: 1em;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-size: 2vh;
        font-weight: 900;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        line-height: 24px;
        width: 80%;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
import React from 'react'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'
import './index.scss'
import {times} from 'lodash'
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'
import {Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {API} from '../../../constants';


class CategorySlider extends React.Component {
  

    render() {
        let {stores} = this.props;
        return (
            <>
          <Carousel className='categoryslider__wrapper'>
                    {times(4, (index) => {
                        return (
                            <Carousel.Item key={index}>
                             {stores && stores.length && stores.map(store => {
                                   if (store.featured_products.length){
                                       return store.featured_products[0].image_url;
                                   }
                                   return stores[0].name;
                                }).filter(image=>image!==undefined).map((image_link, i )=> {
                        return (
                            <Col key={image_link + "" + i} className="col-4 category" >
                                <img src={API.files.detail.replace('/files/:fileUUID/', image_link)} alt=""></img>
                             <p>{stores[i].name}</p>
                                </Col>
                                )
                            })}
                            </Carousel.Item >
                        )
                    })}
          </Carousel>                     
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(CategorySlider);
```

Comment: there is a really good component that will do the work for you. Check it out https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper